# Find a basis for the vectorspace $V$ spanned by vectors $w_1=(1,1,0)$,$w_2=(0,1,1)$, $w_3=(2,3,1)$, and $w_4=(1,1,1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the vectorspace $V$ spanned by vectors $w_1=(1,1,0)$,$w_2=(0,1,1)$, $w_3=(2,3,1)$, and $w_4=(1,1,1)$.

My confusion. Can I form a matrix whose rows are $w_1 w_2 w_3 w_4$ and then reduce this matrix to Echelon form. The non zero rows will be basis.
Can I also take matrix with $w_1 w_2 w_3 w_4$ as a column vectors?
Then what will be basis?

Kindly clear my doubt

Comment: When you say "Then what will be basis?" are you asking about the basis for the column space?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you arrange your $4$ vectors as columns vectors in a $3\times 4$ matrix,  and reduce this matrix, then the resulting columns will be a basis to the span of your original $4$ vectors.

Comment: You need three of them, since $V$ is three-dimensional : eject one of them (e.g. $w_3$, because $w_3 = 2w_1 + w_2$) and show that the three remaining ones are linearly independent (e.g. by checking that their determinant doesn't vanish).

Comment: You can think (as @Abezhiko does), or you can work (row reduction).

Answer (score 1):

If you apply Row operations on the matrix whose columns are $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$, the column space of this matrix would be changed. However, the columns containing leading 1's in the reduced row echelon form will correspond to the linearly independent columns in the original matrix.